# Arbitrary shape pads

Tags: eaglecad

I am having problems trying to design a device with rectangular pads in Eagle:

[image: board with rectangular pads]

I tried to model them has a pad enclosed by rectangles on the top and bottom layers, as described in this tutorial [Arbitrary Pad Shapes](https://youtu.be/_G0ikZKB_Ss):

[image: footprint]

Unfortunately I get an overlap error doing the DRC check. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the tutorial mentioned Eagle version

Comment: @jsotola They mentioned version 6 and I am using version 9. Is something changed about arbitrary pad shapes?

Comment: Although I am not an Eagle user, your problem is probably caused by the pad and the copper shapes that you added are not part of the same net.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I have defined the enclosing pads using the rectangle command but the tutorial was using polygons.